# Javascript multiply of 2 fields with answer in 3rd inside a PHP while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, field

I am showing an records from a quantity and price list for parts used from a MySQL table and updating any changes back to the database but I also need to have a calculated field that quantity * price = Amount.
I just cant quite seem to get it working. I am new to JavaScript. 
I used a GetElementById and it showed a NaN in the first total I then thought about it and I think it may be going through the whole table.

So  have tried to create a dynamic id when in the while loop but cannot get it to show. I'm not exactly sure if I am even on the right track of how to achieve the calculation without submitting the page.
any help would be appreciated
thank you.

```
<?php
while ($list_parts = mysqli_fetch_array($parts_result))
{
    echo " <table border ='0' table width = 95%>";
    echo '<td> <input type="hidden" value="'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'" name="changed_unique_id[]">';
    echo '<td> <input type="hidden" value="'.$list_parts['job_number'].'" name="changed_job_number[]">';
    echo '<td> Quantity   <input type="text"  value="'.$list_parts['qty'].'" name="changed_part_quantity[]" id="qty'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'" onkeypress="qty'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'">';
    echo '<td> Description <input type="text" value="'.$list_parts['item_description'].'" name="changed_item_description[]">';
    echo '<td> Part Number <input type="text" value="'.$list_parts['part_number'].'" name="changed_part_number[]">';
    echo '<td> Part Price <input type="text"  value="'.$list_parts['price'].'" name="changed_part_price[]" id="price'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'" onkeypress="price'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'">';
    echo '<td> Total <input type="text" value="'.$list_parts['sub_total'].'" name="changed_part_sub[]" id="total'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'" >';
    echo "</tr>";   
}
echo "</table>";        
?>
```

My JavaScript is as follows

```
function showtotal(){
    var quantity = document.getElementById("qty'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'").value;
    var price = document.getElementById("price'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'").value;
    var sum = parseInt(quantity) + parseInt(price);
    document.getElementById("total'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'").value = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank you very much Ted for the help. your post helped me solve it by showing me how the theory of it works. after it wouldn't let me use the php in the javascript. I tried a slightly different way. 
I'm not quite sure if this is the formal way of doing it though but still really happy.

```
        while ($list_parts = mysqli_fetch_array($parts_result))
            {
                echo "<table border ='0' table width = 95%>";
                echo '<td> <input type="hidden" value="'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'" name="changed_unique_id[]">';
                echo '<td> <input type="hidden" value="'.$list_parts['job_number'].'" name="changed_job_number[]">';
                echo '<td> Quantity   <input type="text" onchange="showtotal('.$list_parts['unique_id'].')" value="'.$list_parts['qty'].'" name="changed_part_quantity[]" id="qty'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'">';
                echo '<td> Description <input type="text" value="'.$list_parts['item_description'].'" name="changed_item_description[]">';
                echo '<td> Part Number <input type="text" value="'.$list_parts['part_number'].'" name="changed_part_number[]">';
                echo '<td> Part Price <input type="text" onchange="showtotal('.$list_parts['unique_id'].')" value="'.$list_parts['price'].'" name="changed_part_price[]" id="price'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'" >';
                echo '<td> Total <input type="text" id="total'.$list_parts['unique_id'].'" value="'.$list_parts['sub_total'].'" name="changed_part_sub[]">';
                echo "</tr>";
                echo $list_parts['unique_id'];
                echo'(total'.$list_parts['unique_id'].')';  
                echo "</table>";
            }

            ?>
```

Javascript

```
function showtotal(id){
var quantity = document.getElementById('qty'+id).value;
var price = document.getElementById('price'+id).value;
var sum = parseInt(quantity,10)*parseInt(price,10); 
document.getElementById('total'+id).value = sum;
```

}

Thank you very much

Rob Grain

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print stuff inside your JavaScript code, you should insert php tags, for both code readability and safety. But the problem was that you are trying to 'add' your "qty" and the result from "$list_parts" with a '.', and that is PHP code, in JavaScript, you use '+'.

I've also noted  that in your PHP code, you create a 'table' element inside the while, but only close it outside. Your code will most definitely have errors then, as multiple 'table's will be open, but only one closed. You should move the closure of the 'table' inside the while loop, or move the opening outside the while loop.

**EDIT** - Inside the getElementById I had writen "qty + " but that was wrong, since your created ID's are only "qty", so the JavaScript was trying to reach an ID that doesn't exist.

So your JavaScript found should be:

```
function showtotal(){
    var quantity = document.getElementById("qty<?php echo $list_parts['unique_id']; ?>").value;
    var price = document.getElementById("price<?php echo $list_parts['unique_id']; ?>").value;
    var sum = parseInt(quantity) + parseInt(price);
    document.getElementById("total<?php echo $list_parts['unique_id']; ?>").value = sum;
}
```

Comment: It's missing the tr opening tag too

Comment: Hello Ted Thank you very much for the very easy to understand reply indeed. I have struggled with the layouts between the two languages. I have just put the code into the form but it still isn't totalling in the field for some reason. I have echoed your variables and yours is certainly working so I am missing something. I will also change to close the table and the <tr> into the code. Did the php in the id seem right to you I think because it is more trial and error i'm wrong between the two somewhere. thanks

Comment: I have been looking and I think i'm close. I have clicked on inspect element in chrome and is am getting the error.  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null                                                                                                                var quantity = document.getElementById("qty + ").value;  it doesn't seem to be accepting the php within the javascript ?

Comment: Well damn, that was my bad with the "+" sign inside. Editing the answer

Comment: Hello Ted, yes thanks for that I did find that and added it but it seems to show an error in the inspect element and just shows (qty+) and not working through the php.

Comment: Is your JavaScript code inside the PHP file? It needs to be so.